# Why does the Ammo bar color change?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

When I use the Plamsa Cell ability, my ammo bar changes from yellow to orange.  Later - while fighting, the ammo bar color switches back and forth between orange and yellow.  What does it mean?

---

- I'm standing around not fighting with Plasma Cell on - the ammo bar is yellow.
- I turn off Plasma cell - still yellow.
- I turn on Plasma cell, when the ability completes the bar turns orange.
- 3 seconds later, back to yellow (plasma cell still is active).

Comment: does Plasma Cell trigger something that lasts for 3 seconde? maybe it shows you when this buff is over

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This indeed indicates the ammo type you are using. It seems to be rather bugged at this time, often forgetting the colour after a short while and reverting back to the default.

Answer (score 3):

It's so you can tell what cell you are using. I.e. plasma cell = orange ammo counter, combat support cell = green ammo counter. It lets you know what cell you have active without having to squint at your hotbars.

Comment: So - why does it change between orange and yellow while Plasma cell is active?

Comment: I believe it's just so you can know what cell you are using - kind of like something in an aircraft HUD letting you know which missles you are using